# How can I move data from one line to another using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading in from a file called which looks like this:

```
label dataset sw sf
1H 1H_2
NOESY_F1eF2e.nv
4807.69238281 4803.07373047
600.402832031 600.402832031
1H.L 1H.P 1H.W 1H.B 1H.E 1H.J 1H.U 1H_2.L 1H_2.P 1H_2.W 1H_2.B 1H_2.E 1H_2.J 1H_2.U vol int stat comment flag0 flag8 flag9
0 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
1 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
2 {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
3 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
4 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H1'} 5.90291 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
5 {2.H1'} 5.90291 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
6 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
7 {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
8 {1.H1'} 5.82020 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
9 {1.H8} 8.13712 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} {2.H8} 7.61004 0.05000 0.10000 ++ {0.0} {} 0.0 100.0000 0 {} 0 0 0
```

I want to get the values from the columns 1H.L, 1H.P, 1H_2.L, and 1H_2.P. 
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

result={}
df = pd.read_csv("peaks_ee.xpk", sep=" ", skiprows=5)

shift1 = df["1H.P"]
shift2 = df["1H_2.P"]

mask = ((shift1>5.1) & (shift1<6)) & ((shift2>7) & (shift2<8.25))

result = df[mask]
result = result[["1H.L","1H.P","1H_2.L","1H_2.P"]]

for col in result.columns:
    if col == ("1H.L") or col==( "1H_2.L"):
        result[col]=result[col].str.strip("{} ")
result.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)
tclust_atom=open("tclust_ppm.txt","w+")
result.to_string(tclust_atom, header=False)
```

This is the output:

```
0     1.H1'  5.82020   2.H8  7.61004
3     1.H1'  5.82020   1.H8  8.13712
5     2.H1'  5.90291   2.H8  7.61004
11    4.H1'  5.74125   3.H6  7.53261
12    3.H1'  5.54935   4.H8  7.49932
15    3.H1'  5.54935   3.H6  7.53261
18    2.H1'  5.90291   3.H6  7.53261
21    4.H1'  5.74125   4.H8  7.49932
27    6.H1'  5.54297   5.H6  7.72158
32    4.H1'  5.74125   5.H6  7.72158
```

What I want my output to look like is this:

```
1.H1'  5.82020 0.3
2.H8  7.61004 0.3  
1.H8  8.13712 0.3
2.H1'  5.90291 0.3   
4.H1'  5.74125 0.3   
3.H6  7.53261 0.3
3.H1'  5.54935 0.3   
4.H8  7.49932 0.3
3.H1'  5.54935 0.3  
3.H6  7.53261 0.3 
6.H1'  5.54297 0.3   
5.H6  7.72158 0.3
```

I want to put all of it into two columns, and i don't want any duplicates of anything. How can I put all the values of the third and fourth columns of my current output into the first and second columns and then not include any duplicates? And how can I add a constant value (0.3) in a third column?

Edit: Updated code:

```
import pandas as pd

result={}
df = pd.read_csv("peaks_ee.xpk", sep=" ", skiprows=5)

shift1 = df["1H.P"]
shift2 = df["1H_2.P"]

mask = ((shift1>5.1) & (shift1<6)) & ((shift2>7) & (shift2<8.25))

result = df[mask]
result = result[["1H.L","1H.P","1H_2.L","1H_2.P"]]

for col in result.columns:
    if col == ("1H.L") or col==( "1H_2.L"):
        result[col]=result[col].str.strip("{} ")

res = pd.lreshape(df, {'atom_name':['1H.L','1H_2.L'], 'ppm':
['1H.P','1H_2.P']}).drop_duplicates()
res['new']=0.3
result.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)

tclust_atom=open("tclust_ppm.txt","w+")
```

## result.to_string(tclust_atom, header=False)

```
res.to_string(tclust_atom, header = False)
```

and this is the output:

```
0    0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0   {1.H1'}  5.82020  0.3
1    0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0    {2.H8}  7.61004  0.3
2    0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0    {1.H8}  8.13712  0.3
5    0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0   {2.H1'}  5.90291  0.3
10   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0    {3.H6}  7.53261  0.3
11   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0   {4.H1'}  5.74125  0.3
12   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0   {3.H1'}  5.54935  0.3
13   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0    {4.H8}  7.49932  0.3
26   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0    {5.H6}  7.72158  0.3
27   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0   {6.H1'}  5.54297  0.3
29   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0   {5.H2'}  4.26210  0.3
35   0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  0.1  ++  {0.0}  {}  0.05  {}  0  0  0  100.0  0  0.0    {7.H8}  8.16859  0.3
```

Comment: Create a new dataframe with the distinct values

Comment: Why would I need to create a new dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC we can use `pd.lreshape`:

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]:
       c1       c2    c3       c4
0   1.H1'  5.82020  2.H8  7.61004
3   1.H1'  5.82020  1.H8  8.13712
5   2.H1'  5.90291  2.H8  7.61004
11  4.H1'  5.74125  3.H6  7.53261
12  3.H1'  5.54935  4.H8  7.49932
15  3.H1'  5.54935  3.H6  7.53261
18  2.H1'  5.90291  3.H6  7.53261
21  4.H1'  5.74125  4.H8  7.49932
27  6.H1'  5.54297  5.H6  7.72158
32  4.H1'  5.74125  5.H6  7.72158

In [43]: res = pd.lreshape(df, {'key':['c1','c3'], 'val':['c2','c4']}).drop_duplicates()

In [44]: res
Out[44]:
      key      val
0   1.H1'  5.82020
2   2.H1'  5.90291
3   4.H1'  5.74125
4   3.H1'  5.54935
8   6.H1'  5.54297
10   2.H8  7.61004
11   1.H8  8.13712
13   3.H6  7.53261
14   4.H8  7.49932
18   5.H6  7.72158
```

> add a third column with just '0.3'

```
In [45]: res['new'] = 0.3

In [46]: res
Out[46]:
      key      val  new
0   1.H1'  5.82020  0.3
2   2.H1'  5.90291  0.3
3   4.H1'  5.74125  0.3
4   3.H1'  5.54935  0.3
8   6.H1'  5.54297  0.3
10   2.H8  7.61004  0.3
11   1.H8  8.13712  0.3
13   3.H6  7.53261  0.3
14   4.H8  7.49932  0.3
18   5.H6  7.72158  0.3
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! I just entered in the code `pd.lreshape(df, {'key':['c1','c3'], 'val':['c2','c4']}).drop_duplicates()` under my code `result.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)` but I'm still getting the same output

Comment: and how can I get rid of the index values and add a third column with just '0.3'?

Comment: Sorry for such an beginner question but what do you mean with 
`In[41]: df` `Out[42]:` and where should I implement the line 
`pd.lreshape(df, {'key':['c1','c3'], 'val':['c2','c4']}).drop_duplicates()` to test out your code?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it again with your updated code, but it still doesn't work. Where in my code should I be inputting your lines of code? I'm putting it inside my for loop underneath the 

`result[col]=result[col].str.strip("{} ") `
 line

Comment: I just tested the code and I'll update my question with the output.

Comment: The last three columns are what I want, how can I get rid of everything else and how do I get rid of the curly braces?

Answer (score 0):

For starters change your line: `result.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True)` to: `result.drop_duplicates(keep=False,inplace=True)`
or you will continue to get at least one duplicate as the operation is keeping the first duplicate occurrence. I made the same mistake when I first read though the docs for `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`. Then for taking the last two columns and adding them to the first two you can do the following, probably not the most efficient way but it has worked for me. Also do the column operations before removing duplicates just in case you run into miss-matched column sizes.

```
result.columns = ["1HL","1HP","1H_2L","1H_2P"]
#remove the '.' in the name to make things easier
new_L = result.1HL.values.tolist()
new_P = result.1HP.values.tolist()
new_03col = []
for i, value in enumerate(result.1H_2L.values):
    new_L.append(value)
    new_P.append(result.1H_2P.values.tolist()[i[)
for i in range(len(new_L)):
    new_03col.append(0.3)
new_results = pd.DataFrame({'1HL':new_L, '1HP':new_P, '03col':new_03col})
```

Comment: I get an error saying 
`File "newice.py", line 24
    new_L = result.1HL.values.tolist()
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

and where in my code should I input your code? Does it matter? Thanks!